# Sql Server trigger triggers with empty inserted and deleted tables

Tags: sql-server

I have defined a trigger on a table that is triggered

`AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE`

There are cases where the trigger fires, with both `INSERTED` AND `DELETED` tables being empty. How can this be possible?

For the records, that's the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AuditUsersTrigger] ON [dbo].[Users]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON


    DECLARE @type nchar(1), @hasChanges bit
    SET @hasChanges = 1
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @type = 'U'

            IF EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM INSERTED i
                INNER JOIN DELETED d ON
                    i.Name = d.Name AND
                    i.Pwd = d.Pwd AND
                    ...
            ) SELECT @hasChanges = 0
        END
        ELSE
            SELECT @type = 'I'
    ELSE
        SELECT @type = 'D'


    IF @type = 'D' OR (@type = 'U' AND @hasChanges = 1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT AuditUsers (
            New, Id, Name, ...
        )
        SELECT
            0, Id, Name, ...
        FROM DELETED

        IF @type = 'D'
        BEGIN
            INSERT AuditUsers (New)
            SELECT 1
        END
    END

    IF @type = 'I' OR (@type = 'U' AND @hasChanges = 1)
    BEGIN
        IF @type = 'I'
        BEGIN
            INSERT AuditUsers (New)
            SELECT 0
        END

        INSERT AuditUsers (
            New, Id, Name, ...
        )
        SELECT
            0, Id, Name, ...
        FROM INSERTED
    END


    IF Trigger_Nestlevel() < 2
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @clientId TABLE (id INT)
        DECLARE @clientCode NVARCHAR(50), @shopId INT;

        IF @type = 'I' OR @type = 'U'
        BEGIN
            SELECT @clientCode = ClientCode, @shopId = ShopId FROM INSERTED;
            INSERT INTO @clientId SELECT id FROM Clients WHERE code = @clientCode;

            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @clientId)
            BEGIN
                INSERT Clients (name, code, active, shopId) OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @clientId
                VALUES (@clientCode, @clientCode, 1, @shopId);
            END


            UPDATE Users SET ClientId = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM @clientId) WHERE ClientCode = @clientCode;
        END
    END
END
```

Comment: can you show the excact definition of your trigger? Does it affect the current table, if so you have a feedback loop

Comment: `UPDATE ABC SET Column = 1 WHERE 1 = 0` - 0 rows affected, the trigger still fires.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [documented behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189799.aspx)

> DML triggers execute when a user tries to modify data through a data manipulation language (DML) event. DML events are INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements on a table or view. **These triggers fire when any valid event is fired, regardless of whether or not any table rows are affected.**

If you have a recurring loop, whereby table A has a trigger that affects table B, and table B has a trigger that affects table A, you can manage this using [TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260618%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), or by checking if either `inserted` or `deleted` contain any rows before actually doing anything.

Comment: I had excluded that case because I tested it. Turns out I tested it the wrong way. I'm already testing the nest level. At least now I know that it is triggered by a delete statement that deletes nothing. Thanks!

Comment: @GarethD `or by checking either table contains any rows` -- is that as simple as `select @hasRows = count(my_primary_key) from deleted; if (@hasRows > 0) ...` ?

Comment: Yes, but don't forget about the `inserted` table too.